# Showing Error Text on TextField in ShowDialog

Tags: flutter, error-handling, textfield

I am trying to build an AlertDialog to reauthenticate user before deleting account. I would like to show error text when reauthentication does not work.
The errors are handled correctly as I can see by using print() statements. However I cannot get the TextField to show the error as a feedback to the user. I think it must be something to do with the state of the SimpleDialog itself, rather than the state of the outer widget...
Here is the code:

```
Future _validate({String email, String password}) async {
    setState(() {
      _wrongEmail = false;
      _wrongPassword = false;
      _emailErrorText = null;
      _passwordErrorText = null;
    });

    try {
      if (await userDataBase.checkCorrectEmail(
          email: email, loggedInUser: widget.user.id)) {
        throw FirebaseAuthException(
            message: 'email is not correct', code: 'user-not-found');
      }
      await userDataBase.authenticateUser(email, password);
    } catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'wrong-passwod') {
        setState(() {
          _passwordErrorText = 'Password not Correct';
        });
      } else if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
        setState(() {
          _emailErrorText = 'Email not Correct';
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          _emailErrorText = 'Email not Correct';
          _passwordErrorText = 'Password not Correct';

          _wrongPassword = true;
          _wrongEmail = true;
        });
      }
      throw e;
    }
  }

  Future _authenticate({String email, String password}) async {
    try {
      await _validate(email: email, password: password);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.code);
      print(_wrongEmail);
      print(_emailErrorText);
      return;
    }

    print('correct behaviour');

    // Navigator.pop(context);
    // setState(() {
    //   _loading = true;
    // });

    // await userDataBase.deleteUser(widget.user.id);
    // Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
  }

  Future _confirmIdentity() {
    final emailController = TextEditingController();
    final passwordController = TextEditingController();
    _emailErrorText = null;
    _passwordErrorText = null;
    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
        content: Container(
          height: 200,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text('Confirm Your Identity'),
              TextField(
                controller: emailController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    errorText: _wrongEmail ? _emailErrorText : null,
                    labelText: 'email'),
              ),
              TextField(
                controller: passwordController,
                decoration: 
                     InputDecoration(
                       errorText: _wrongPassword ? _passwordErrorText : null, 
                       labelText: 'password'
                     ),
              ),
              Spacer(),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      _authenticate(
                          email: emailController.text,
                          password: passwordController.text);
                    },
                    child: Text('Confirm'),
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                    child: Text('Cancel'),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Thank you. I can post all the widget code ecc. if you need it: it is a statefull widget.

Answer (score 0):

For 1st 2 if conditions, you are setting the error message, but not setting the respective boolean flags to true.
Example:

```
if (e.code == 'wrong-passwod') {
    setState(() {
      _passwordErrorText = 'Password not Correct';
    });
  }
```

Here, in the `setState()`function, you will also need to set `_wrongPassword = true;`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. The boolean variables _wrongPassword, _wrongEmail are not necessary seen as when the _PasswordErrorText or _EmailErrorText are null, the error text is not displayed by default.

It is necessary to build a statefull widget that is the content of ShowDialog! then everything works.